# How to initialize contour in OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I want to use [drawContours](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contours#cv-drawcontours) function in O

```
 vector<vector<Point> > contours;
```

**How to assign the following (x,y) to the variable contours?**

```
x = [194, 253, 293, 245]
y = [72, 14, 76, 125]
```

Can anyone help me out??

Comment: Is that a single contour?

Comment: ya...a square contour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, you can easily initialise your `contours` vector:

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours = {{{194, 72}, {253, 14}, {293, 76}, {245, 125}}};
```

Note that `contours` is a `vector` of contours, where each contour is a `vector<Point>`. So its a container of containers of points.

Comment: As I said, this is C++11. Are you compiling with a C++11 compiler? For GCC, add the `-std=c++0x` option.

Answer (score 2):

Is this code can help you ?

```
vector<Point> firstContour;
firstContour.push_back(Point(194,72));
firstContour.push_back(Point(253,14));
firstContour.push_back(Point(293,76));
firstContour.push_back(Point(245,125));
contours.push_back(firstContour);
```